# How to run specific tests using SBT Jenkins Plugin for ScalaTest test

Tags: jenkins, sbt, scalatest

Currently we are using IntelliJ, Scala, SBT to kick off our tests in our local enviroment. With SBT command line, we can specify specific test, suites, wildcards, as instructed here:

[ScalaTest.org Page](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt)

Such as "test-only *RedSuite"

However on our CI Jenkins server, with the SBT pluging, when specifying this, it gives an error.

In the action field, the following values were used:

Action:compile test-only test.package.name

Using the following does work for ALL tests:

Action:compile test

```
[success] Total time: 240 s, completed Apr 28, 2014 12:29:36 PM
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: org (similar: export)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: org (similar: fork, run, doc)
[error] org.company.scalatest.abc.regressionsuite
[error]    ^
Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Recording test results
```

Does anyone know if there is a way we can pass these parameters through the jenkins SBT plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a quoting problem, your Action field is parsed as 3 commands:

- `compile`
- `test-only`
- `org.company.scalatest.abc.regressionsuite`

And it chokes because that `org` is not a valid command.

Using `compile "test-only org.company.scalatest.abc.regressionsuite"` should fix that.

Comment: After re-reading the SBT documentation, I thought the mistake was using test-only instead of testOnly. TestOnly(with Parameters in quotes)did exactly what we wanted, and going back and trying gourlaysama's suggestion also worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user1697841 use `testOnly` if possible: `test-only` is the old syntax (before sbt 0.13), `testOnly` the new one (only supported in sbt 0.13+). The old one is still supported for backward compatibility, but will disappear someday.